# C# entity framework make second call to query database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to fetch each user's manager details. Here is my linq query. But getting the following error:

**A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed.
This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however, instance members are not guaranteed to be thread-safe**

Main method:

```
public async Task<IList<SecurityAdminUser>> AllSecurityAdminUsers()
    {
        return await _context.User
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(u => !u.Disabled)
            .Select(u => MapToSecurityAdminUser(u, 0))
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

Second method:

```
    private SecurityAdminUser MapToSecurityAdminUser(EntityUser u, int loopCount)
    {
        //Only return the first level
        if (loopCount > 1) return null; 

        return new SecurityAdminUser
        {
            UserGuid = u.UserGuid,
            AccountName = u.AccountName,
            FirstName = u.Forename,
            LastName = u.Surname,
            Email = u.Email,
            KnownAs = u.KnownAs,
            Disabled = u.Disabled,
            OriginalHireStartDate = u.OriginalHireStartDate,
            TerminationDate = u.TerminationDate,
            ManagerUser = u.ManagerId != null ? MapToSecurityAdminManagerUser(u, loopCount) : null
        };
    }

    private SecurityAdminUser MapToSecurityAdminManagerUser(EntityUser u, int loopCount)
    {
```

//Getting error here

```
        var managerUser = _context.User.Where(manager => manager.Id == u.ManagerId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (managerUser == null) return null;

        loopCount++;
        return MapToSecurityAdminUser(managerUser, loopCount);
    }
```

Comment: Note that you also need to add a stopping condition to MapToSecurityAdminManagerUser, otherwise you will always get `null` from there. And even after you fix the issue you're facing, you would be making not 2, but `(1+users.Count)` requests to the database - one to get the users, and then one per user to get the manager. You might want to optimize this if you have many users in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because your `MapToSecurityAdminManagerUser` method, which tries to execute a new query, is called (via `MapToSecurityAdminUser`) from the `Select` expression used by the query in your main method.

The fastest way to fix your code would be to change the main method so that the mapping happens after the first query has finished, something like this:

```
public async Task<IList<SecurityAdminUser>> AllSecurityAdminUsers()
{
    var users = await _context.User
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(u => !u.Disabled)
        .ToListAsync();

    return users.Select(u => MapToSecurityAdminUser(u, 0)).ToList();
}
```